# undefined local variable or method `destroy' for CommentsController:Class in my destroy comment method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've added a comment feature in my app and so far everything's working fine until this error came up. What I did is that I added a delete comment feature. Everything shows normal when I fire up the server, but the problem comes in after I click the 'delete' button.

Error message

> undefined local variable or method `destroy' for CommentsController:Class

Anyway, here's my code.

Comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comments_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    #redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :commenter, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Comment view partial

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='comments col-md-6'>
        <p>
          <b><%= comment.commenter %>:</b>
          <p><span><%= comment.body %></span></p>
        </p>

        <%= button_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment],
               method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  %>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment form

```
<div class='form-group col-md-5'>

<%= form_for([@posts, @posts.comments.build]) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label 'Add a comment' %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', rows: '3' %>
    </div>
      <%= f.hidden_field :commenter, value: current_user.name %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
        <div class='back-button'>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>

</div>
```

help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

This is the link to my github repo. just in case anyone would like to tinker on it.

https://github.com/ridata14/BlogApp

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `destroy' for CommentsController:Class

Comment: Do you have a route for the destroy action?

Comment: method `destroy` in `CommentsController` is instance method, so did you call it like this? `CommentsController.new.destroy`

Comment: nope, i don't have a route for the destroy action. it is nested under the Posts controller. resources :posts do 
    resources :comments
  end

Comment: i called it using @comment.destroy

Comment: Are you sure the error refers to that line?

Comment: not quite sure, it occurs everytime i click the delete link.

Comment: Can you also post the view where these partials are used? The error suggests that the comment you are looking for with Comment.find is not being found, hence you can't call destroy on it.

Comment: ill just give a link to my repository. thanks in advance https://github.com/ridata14/BlogApp

Comment: @JimEdelstein Im also thinking about that, maybe something wrong with my Delete link. I am passing it to [comment.post, comment] I'm pretty unsure with this variables.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I looked at the repo. You have a comments table but no model.  `rails generate model Comment`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i miss the point, but you can't call instance method without define it like class method or without create instance.

The error

> undefined local variable or method `destroy' for CommentsController:Class

so if you call `CommentsController.destroy`, you call instance method `destroy` with no instance, so this generates error.

is same like this case

```
class Foo
  def destroy
    puts "destroy"
  end
end

Foo.destroy
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for Foo:Class
```

But you can do this

```
class Bar
  def self.destroy
    puts "destroy"
  end
end

Bar.destroy
# => "destroy"
```

or call it like this

```
Foo.new.destroy
# => "destroy"
```

Am i wrong?

Comment: i think i get your point. I can create and view my posts in my page, meaning that I have successfully instantiated a comment. kinda weird though, coz this is the same exact code from one of the rails tutorials.

Comment: @StormTrooper What is in `ApplicationController` or did you create instance of `CommentsController ` somewere? I rly try to figure this out what is going on here:D

Comment: CommentController stated above, nothing relevant inside ApplicationController, just some devise stuff and all.

Comment: @StormTrooper and are you create instance of  `CommentsController` ? Or did you say that `destroy` method is class method?

Comment: @StormTrooper Sou you need to create new instance or set `destroy` to class method. Try it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the comment object along with the destroy method as a paramete, so that the controller recognizes it.

You have to get the post of that article and delete the comment according to the link i have given.

```js
 def destroy
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
   @comment.destroy
   redirect_to post_path(@post)
 end
```

```html
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

[For help refer to this guide in delete section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Comment: thanks for looking into this. tried running this snippet. since my comment is nested under the posts controller. Instead of comment_path(comment), I used post_comment_path(comment) ... the error returned was this...  "No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil, ...**some comment parameters*** missing required keys: [:id]"

Comment: Please give 'method: :delete' to go to destroy action, if not given it goes to show action.                                                                                                  You have destroy method in comments controller?

Comment: give the output of rake routes

Comment: yes i did that, sorry for not posting the full syntax. this is the code that i ran. <%= link_to 'Delete', post_comment_path(comment),
                   method: :delete, 
                   class: 'delete-link'  %> ...same outcome. No route matches.

Comment: @Dias here's my routes output. https://gist.github.com/ridata14/167a0eeae0031a09c81c

Comment: I have changed the ans and added some code in destroy method, please try that.

Comment: @StormTrooper are you getting now comment id as params

Comment: @Sravan tried the code. error "undefined method `    ' for #<CommentsController:0x007f65ee90efb0>" shows up and its pointing out to the @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id]) line.

Comment: I think your post must have got deleted which is giving the error.Please check the render text: @post and check it

Comment: my post is still there, I can view it together with its comments. my only problem is deleting a comment. which leads to the error(s) stated above.

Answer (score 0):

should pass post object in the path since comments resource is nested under posts

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', post_comment_path(post, comment), method: :delete, class: 'delete-link' %>
```

Comment: this is also outputting an error that my @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id]) line has an undefined method.